# Let $\{X_n\}$ be i.i.d integrable r.v.s, show that $\frac{1}{n}\max_{1\leq j\leq n}|X_j|\to 0 \quad \mbox{a.e.}$

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence, random-variables

This problem is an exercise in *Probability theory,independence,interchangeable, martingale*(Chow), exercise 4.1.10.

Let $\{X_n,n\geq 1\}$ be independent identical distributed integrable random variables, then
$$\frac{1}{n}\max_{1\leq j\leq n}|X_j|\to 0 \quad \mbox{a.e.}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Show and use the following facts:

1. If $\{Y_n\}$ is a sequence of random variables such that for each $\varepsilon>0$, 
   $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}P(|Y_n|\geqslant \varepsilon)<\infty,$$
   then the sequence $\{Y_n\}$ converges to $0$ almost surely.
2. If $X$ is an integrable random variable, then the series $\sum_n P(|X|>n)$ is convergent.

Answer (score 1):

Davide provided a good hint, I just give some supplementary, since this is a question I want to know long ago.

For any fixed $\epsilon>0,$
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}P(|X_n|>n\epsilon)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}P(|X|>n\epsilon)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}P(\frac{|X|}{\epsilon}>n)<\infty
$$
because $\mathbb{E}[\,\frac{|X|}{\epsilon}]<\infty$. Apply Borel-Cantelli lemma,
$$ P(|X_n|>n\epsilon\quad i.o.)=0
$$
which implies $P(|X_n|\le n\epsilon\quad e.v.)=1$. With probability $1$, $\exists\; N(\omega)>0$ such that
$$
 |X_n|\le n\epsilon\quad \text{for}\ \;n>N
$$
Hence there exists an even greater integer $N_1(\omega)>0$ (because $\max|X_j|$ grows less faster than $n\epsilon$) such that
$$
 \max_{1\le j\le n}|X_j|\le n\epsilon\ \Longleftrightarrow \frac{1}{n}\max_{1\le j\le n}|X_j|\le \epsilon\quad \text{for}\ \;n>N_1
$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Actually, this original question is:
If $\{X_n\}$ are i.i.d r.v.s, then:
$\frac{1}{n}\max_{1\leq j\leq n}|X_j|\to 0 \quad \mbox{a.e.}$
iff $X_1$ is integrable;
$\frac{1}{n}\max_{1\leq j\leq n}|X_j|\to 0 \quad \mbox{in P.}$
iff $n P(|X_1|>n)\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$;

Comment: Since you are interesting in it, I give the origin question here.